# Is there a way to associate an enum literal with classes in UML class diagram?

Tags: enums, uml, enumeration, class-diagram

I'm trying to design a UML class diagram that represents Users that interact with other classes based on their roles, I've chosen to represent Roles as an enum class like so :
[image: user-role-class-diagram]

What i'd like to represent is that only a user with a Role ADMIN can create a project, only a MANAGER can modify it and every CONSULTANT can only participate in it, can this be achievable with enum representation for Roles?

Comment: can i use uml constraints for that?

Comment: "*can i use uml constraints for that?*" : yes

Comment: but out of that your relation between *User* and *RoleName* is wrong, first there is no reason for a *RoleName* to know the *Users* (and an *enum* cannot do that) , so the relation must be directional (`User ---> RoleName`), and second using the multiplicity "*" that means a given *User* can have several roles, is it true ?

Comment: @bruno yes you're right i'll modify the question and also i'll add my answer using uml constraints.

Comment: Frankly speaking I you are not interested by my answer better I delete it being useless ...

Answer (score 1):

A solution is to use uml constraints like so:

[image: solution]

Comment: Their are some errors/typos in your diagrams, finally I put an answer to indicate them in a better way than through remarks on that answer

Answer (score 1):

Being an enumeration *RoleName* is better drawn with `<<enumeration>>` (like in the Figure 7.1 - Class Diagram Example page 7 of [Object Constraint Language - formal/2014-02-03](http://www.omg.org/spec/OCL/2.4) )

If *Role* is only an envelop for *RoleName* that class is useless (this is what I suppose in the diagram below)

The relations *create, manage, participate* do not represent attributes, the multiplicities have non sense in that context. The relation *role* has the default multiplicity 1

Your constraints are pre-conditions, their context is the class *User* and in OCL the equality operator is "=", so your diagram can be :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing static representation and behavior. The `User` has **one** association to `Project` (not 3 different ones):

[image]

The different behavior (derived from some UC) can be shown in a collaboration. E.g. in an AD like this:

[image]

Just a sketch, but that should give you the gist.